# 7w LED bulb in a 5W led fitting

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, led

in wall sconces to go above my bed and I want to get some smart bulbs to connect to my Alexa but I want them to have a filament bulb. I found these Philips HUE bulbs that I like: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07SNGBWG4/ref=crt_ewc_title_oth_2?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE

My light fitting says that they need a 5W LED or MAX 42W Halogen bulb, but the Philips hue bulbs are a 7W LED but their Incandescent Equivalent is 40 watts. Can I use these bulbs? or do I need to find new bulbs?

Comment: you would have to use six of the bulbs to reach the 42 W maximum, so one is no problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these will work fine. The "5 watt" is the minimum for your fixture to dim. The 42 watt halogen maximum is, for the most part, a heat maximum and led bulbs don't generate anywhere near the heat of a halogen bulb. This is a 220 volt bulb.